# MongoDB $in with subquery

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this set of collection below..

teams collection:

```
{
   total: 3
   data: [
      {
         "_id": "t1",
         "name": "white horse",
         "leader_id": "L1"
         "teamScore": 12,
         "active": 1
      },
      {
         "_id": "t2",
         "name": "green hornets",
         "leader_id": "L2",
         "teamScore": 9,
         "active": 1
      },
      {
         "_id": "t3",
         "name": "pink flaminggo",
         "leader_id": "L3",
         "teamScore": 22,
         "active": 1
      },
   ]
}
```

leaders collection:

```
{
   total: 3
   data: [
      {
         "_id": "L1",
         "name": "John Doe",
         "organization": "Software Development",
         "active": 1
      },
      {
         "_id": "L2",
         "name": "Peter Piper",
         "organization": "Software Development"
         "active": 1
      },
      {
         "_id": "L3",
         "name": "Mary Lamb",
         "organization": "Accounting Department"
         "active": 1
      },
   ]
}
```

The query should look like this: `SELECT * FROM teams WHERE active = 1 AND leader_id IN (SELECT id FROM leaders WHERE organization = 'Software Development')`

I am new to mongodb and my question is how can the query above be converted in mongoDB aggregation framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) with pipeline,

- `$match` will check `active` status
- `$lookup` will join leaders collection

  - `$match` to check `leader_id` and `organization`
- `$match` check leaders is not `[]` empty
- `$project` to remove `leaders` field

```
db.teams.aggregate([
  { $match: { active: 1 } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "leaders",
      let: { leader_id: "$leader_id" },
      as: "leaders",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $and: [
              { $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$leader_id"] } },
              { organization: "Software Development" }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $match: { leaders: { $ne: [] } } },
  { $project: { leaders: 0 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/W7eFdkUTpsE)

Comment: I'm excited, is `data` an output from monogse? or does he have data as an array in collection?

Comment: @varman the original documents in collection are inside `data` field. might be OP is new to ask question for mongodb in SO.

Comment: Ahh. Thats fine. But he hasn't mentioned mongooes

Comment: @varman yup but its not related with mongoose, i have just predicted, look at mysql query there is no `data` field mentioned.

Comment: @varman and second if someone asking for query then he/she probability working on API side and  this is the usual structure `(data, message, total/count)` of API response and we can predict this is copied from any api response.

Comment: @turivishal Your code works like charm! Do you mind if i ask you one more? Would you be able to explain to me (in the most simple way) whats going on inside the `lookup` block specially in the `pipeline`? I only use the lookup along with the foreignField and localField. Thank you!

Comment: @DevWannabe this is lookup with aggregation pipeline, look at the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#consideration) you can specify your own conditions using pipelines, join will be on the matching conditions in pipeline.