# MongoDB update with subquery from another collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Given this data below from mongoDB:

Teams Collection:

```
{
   id: 1,
   name: "white horse",
   leader_id: "L1",
   active: 1
},
{
   id: 2,
   name: "green hornets",
   leader_id: "L2",
   active: 1
},
{
   id: 3,
   name: "pink flaminggo",
   leader_id: "L3",
   active: 1
}
```

Users Collection:

```
{
   id: "L1",
   name: "John Doe",
   organization: "Software Development",
   active: 1
},
{
   id: "L2",
   name: "Peter Piper",
   organization: "Software Development",
   active: 1
},
{
   id: "L3",
   name: "Mary Lamb",
   organization: "Accounting Department",
   active: 1
}
```

How can we rewrite and execute this sql update query `UPDATE teams SET active = 0 WHERE id = 3 AND leader_id IN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE organization = 'Accounting Department')` to mongodb query?

Comment: See this [SQL to MongoDB Mapping Chart](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/sql-comparison/index.html).

Comment: You would use $match, $lookup and $merge for this.

Comment: You can't do it with update single query, you need to divide in 2 queries first select and then update, or use [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) in aggregate() method, i think this is same question that i [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63573853/mongodb-in-with-subquery) for aggregation, before use at least read about `$out` how it works and it is helpful to you or not.

Comment: @turivishal do you mean i need to make 2 queries like First query is targeting the data to be updated and then the second query is where the update query will happen? Sorry for being repetitive I just wanna make sure that i am getting your point.

Comment: @DevWannabe yes first you need to get users ids on the base of organization and then second you can update checking leader_id in that you have retrieved from first query.